# How to make Postfix null client save a copy of sent email to Office 365 sent items folder

Tags: postfix

We've got bit of software that is sending email by smtp which unfortunately isn't configured to save a copy of the sent mail to any folder.  The client is on Office 365 and there's no way at present to configure it to save emails sent through smtp client to a sent folder.

I want to setup postfix on site to act as a null client, receive all the emails from this software, forward them directly to Office 365's smtp server and finally save a copy to Office 365's imap sent folder for the sending user.

Is this even possible?  I've looked into always_bcc and sender and recipient bcc_maps but these will only save the emails to peoples inbox...

Answer (score 0):

Postfix is a Message Transport Agent (MTA), or you can say it is *a postman*. Its main responsibility is delivering email across server. There is no email saving feature incorporated to posfix built-in capability. You can find that capability in a Message Delivery Agent (MDA) software, such as dovecot or maildrop.

Of course there is a possible workaround for your scenario

1. Use postfix to send BCC email to another mailbox
2. Setup a script to move email from INBOX folder in that mailbox to another Sent Item folder.